# Can a rollup plugin get access to the entire module dependency graph?

Tags: rollupjs

I've got a rollup plugin I maintain and part of what it does requires it knowing about *every* module in the project. I don't know of a good way to get this information though.

- `resolveId()` won't get called if the file was already resolved by any plugin further up the chain
- `generateBundle()` doesn't include any modules that were tree-shaken away

Is there another hook I could use to get access to the module + importer information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `this.getModuleInfo(id)`. If you have the ids of the entry points, this will give you all imported ids and basically let you crawl the whole graph. Note that during the build phase, plugins can emit additional entry points so you might want to use the Information from generateBundle as a starting point.